# Can you cook bone stock in two hours, if not what are the problems?

Tags: bones, chicken-stock

I tried to make my first stock, used 1 chicken carcass, brought to boil and simmered all in 2 hours.  Regrigerated it and next day everything was gel.  I know recipes say it should be 6-24 hours however isn't my one considered a success?

What things am I missing out on by not cooking for half a day?

Comment: Chicken stock is often simmered for 2-3 hours. Larger boned animals (beef) is cooked longer, 4-6 hours. What you would miss is some flavor and some gelatin. I don't have any source, so I'm leaving this as a comment... :p

Answer (score 8):

Refrigerated stock is supposed to gel. Its caused by the gelatin you're (intentionally!) extracting from the bones.

To determine if its a success, you'd taste it. Assuming it tastes right, then its a success. If you had you cooked it longer, you may have extracted a little more flavor & gelatin (so it'd be an even thicker gel).

You can also make chicken stock in a slow cooker (if you want an easy way to let it simmer all day), or in a pressure cooker (if you want to make stock in a hour). The taste of these methods will be slightly different, and for best taste pressure-cooker stock [requires a non-venting pressure cooker](http://www.cookingissues.com/2009/11/22/pressure-cooked-stocks-we-got-schooled/#more-2561) running at [15 psi](http://www.cookingissues.com/2010/01/27/pressure-cooked-stock-2-changing-pressures-playing-with-chemistry/#more-3243).